# LoginActivity in android not getting php json

Tags: php, android

I'm making an app  where my registration works fine only that my login is not working my `php` script is working fine only in login it is saying `json` mismatch
here is my loginactivity

Just in login it is giving error apart from that everything is working fine
i checked `php json response` it is same as i have given in android still not working i don't know where i'm going wrong

**sample json response**

> [{"code":"login_success","username":"smith","password":"55fd64d3d40f601a78f7917de5a10e6044a5e74d"}]

**Error Response**

> [{"code":"login_failed","message":"User not found... Please try again"}]

Please find my Login Page:

```
public void login(View view) {


mProgress.show();
    username = editusername.getEditText().getText().toString();
    password = editpasword.getEditText().getText().toString();
    Prefs prefs = new Prefs(LoginActivity.this);
    prefs.setName(username);

                if(username.equals("") || password.equals("")){
                    displayAlert("Enter a valid username and password");
                }
                else{
                   StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                           new Response.Listener<String>() {
                               @Override
                               public void onResponse(String response) {
                                   try {
                                       JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response); //on this line it is giving error
                                       JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                       String code = jsonObject.getString("code");
                                       if(code.equals("login_failed")){
                                          builder.setTitle("Login Error..");
                                          displayAlert(jsonObject.getString("message"));
                                       }
                                       else {
                                           Intent intent  = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Work.class);
                                           startActivity(intent);
                                       }

                                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                                   }
                               }
                           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            displayAlert("Internet Connection problem");
                       }
                   }){
                       @Override
                       protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                           Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                           params.put("username",username);
                           params.put("password",password);
                           return params;
                       }
                   };
                   Singleton.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).addToREquestQueue(stringRequest);
                }
            }
            public void displayAlert(String message){
                builder.setMessage(message);
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        editpasword.getEditText().setText("");
                        editusername.getEditText().setText("");
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
```

SharedPreference.java

```
public class Prefs {
    Context context;
    private String name;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public void removeUser(){
        sharedPreferences.edit().clear().commit();
    }

    public String getName() {
        name = sharedPreferences.getString("userdata","");
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("userdata",name).commit();
    }

    public Prefs(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("userinfo",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

Please see my Logcat detail:-

> at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
>           04-03 11:12:47.588 14388-14388/kashyapinfotech.com.officework W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
>           04-03 11:12:48.097 14388-14388/kashyapinfotech.com.officework W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value (JSONArray.java:96)
>                   at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:108)
>                   at kashyapinfotech.com.officework.LoginActivity$1.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:68)
>                   at kashyapinfotech.com.officework.LoginActivity$1.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:64)
>                   at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
>           04-03 11:12:48.098 14388-14388/kashyapinfotech.com.officework W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
>                   at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
>                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)

I checked `php` it is working fine so here is `php` script

```
<?php
            include("conn.php");
            if(isset($_POST['btn_login'])){
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $password = sha1($password);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            $response = array();
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
                $username = $row[1];
                $password = $row[3];
                $code = "login_success";
                array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"username"=>$username,"password"=>$password));
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
            else{
                $code = "login_failed";
                $message = "User not found... Please try again";
                array_push($response, array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);

            }
            ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username">
            <input type="text" name="password">
            <input type="submit" name="btn_login">
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: please provide sample json response

Comment: please check i added sample json response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for a key `btn_login` in your **php code** which you are not posting from your **android end**, for example it should be

```
 params.put("username",username);
 params.put("password",password);
 params.put("btn_login","some data");
```

or if you dont need `btn_login`, remove it from php code

Comment: i have one more question can i ask you

Comment: sure, please ask

Comment: i have added shred preference but somehow it doesnt seem to be working and i have also added progress bar but after giving wrong credentials progress bar doesnt stop and my shared preference is not storing data

Comment: should i post updated code along with shared preference

Comment: if its not related to your **question's title**, you should add a new question for it,try adding new question and share the link here

Comment: sir i want to post question because i can post question once in every 90 minutes

Comment: i can add shred preference code here and you can see where i'm going wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168091/discussion-between-navneet--and-smith).

Answer (score 0):

Try This Way :

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,new Response.Listener<String>() {
   @Override
   public void onResponse(String response) 
    {   
      try {
          JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(0);
          String code = jresponse.getString("code");
           if(code.equals("login_success")){
             // login successful

               String username = jresponse.getString("username");
               String password = jresponse.getString("password");
           }else{
             // login failed

               String message = jresponse.getString("message");
           }

          }catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

    }
```

Comment: response.getJSONObject showing cannot resolve method